# xamp windows 7 apache not loading

Tags: windows, apache

I get this message:

```
Status change detected: stopped
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums
```

all other services load, bar apache

Comment: what says the error logs? Currently running `Skype` or `TeamViewer`?

Answer (score 0):

this may happen often because of other programs using the port 80 or 443 which Apache uses.

I ran into this issue with Skype and I had to configure it to use another port rather than 443.

Check your port by typing in your command line `netstat -np TCP | find "80"` and for port 443 to see the network status of them.

Check your Skype configurations for the ports :
Tools->Options->Advanced->Connections and uncheck the button that says "Use port 80 and 443 ..."